# Python check number is less than

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
if uservar[0][0] == text_hashed:
                sql = "SELECT expires FROM akeys WHERE user = %s"
                var = (message.author.id,)
                mycursor.execute(sql, var)
                myresultrank = mycursor.fetchall()
                guild = client.get_guild(CENSORED)

                if myresultrank < 1:
                    print("Less")
                else:
                    print("Normal")

                sql = """UPDATE akeys SET user = %s WHERE license = %s"""
                val = (message.author.id, text_hashed)
                mycursor.execute(sql, val)
                mydb.commit()
```

Im trying to check if the number in the data base is less than 1 but i get this error

```
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "My Path", line 529, in 
on_message
if myresultrank < 1:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: As stated in the error message, `myresultrank` is a list. You could try to print it if you don't know what it is supposed to contain.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `fetchall()` gets all the datas into a list. now inorder to check if elements count use **len**. If you want the the database element take first element and typecast to integer if necessary **int(myresultrank[0])**

Answer (score 0):

`fetchall()` gets you ALL the records that match, hence the "list" mentioned in your error message. You need to access an element in the myresultrank list. You cannot compare a query result list to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

try these changes

```
                myresultrank = mycursor.fetchone()
```

.
.
.

```
                if myresultrank[0] < 1:
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Answer (score 0):

This line is returning a `list`:

```
myresultrank = mycursor.fetchall()
```

Later, we are attempting to compare the list to an integer, which is causing your error.

IF the list contains a value that you want to extract so that you can compare it to the integer (int), it may be possible to index that value in a manner similar to this:

```
if myresultrank[i] < 1:
```

where `i` is the position in the list that stores the value you care about.